# Unable to filter the first row in terminal by AWK

Tags: awk, match

I tried the following code unsuccessfully after using ls -1

```
awk -F '\n' '{ print $1 }'
```

How can I get the first row in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0 ; exit(0); }'
```

I agree that `head -1` is easier.

Other option:

```
sed q file
```

Answer (score 3):

head -n 1

Might be easier.

If you insist on awk, do

awk 'NR == 1 { print }'